# AJAX button firing off all buttons on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a modal full of comments. My code takes a JSON array and posts the first index as the original post, then iterates through the rest as replies, and creates AJAX listeners for each post. When I click the AJAX button, only the original post buttons work, and when I click like on the original post, it seems to fire off 4 times (the number of replies in my example).

[image]

I've tried to move the code for the AJAX listeners and I've removed the AJAX listener for the original posts, but it still seems to work and fire off multiple times.

This is my function that generates the model...

```
function ShowCommentsModal (res)
        {

$('.modal').modal('show')    
//Set HTML for main comment here
$('.ModalPost').html(
    '<div id="Post"><div id="UserInfoDiv">// HTML CODE FOR ORIGINAL POST
        );
        // REMOVED CODE FOR REPOST AJAX HERE

//Set HTML for comments here
    res.shift();
    $('.CommentArea').html(''); // Clear HTML
    $.each(res, function(index) {    // Start of foreach loop            

$('.CommentArea').html(
     $('.CommentArea').html() +                                              
        // COMMENT HTML HERE
        )
     $('[data-likes]').click(function() {
    var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-likes');
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "api/likes?id=" + $(this).attr('data-likes'),
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: '',
        success: function(r) {
           var res = JSON.parse(r)
            console.log(r)
            $("[data-likes... //update like button')
          },
        error: function(r) { console.log(r) }
        }); // END OF AJAX
    }); //END OF DATA-LIKES CLICK FUNCTION
        $('[data-comment]').click(function() {
                var buttonid = $(this).attr('data-comment');
              $.ajax({
                      type: "GET",
              url: "api/comments?postid=" + $(this).attr('data-comment'),
              processData: false,
              contentType: "application/json",
              data: '',
              success: function(r) {
                var res = JSON.parse(r)
            console.log(res)
            ShowCommentsModal.call(res);
            },
              error: function(r) { console.log(r) }
        }); //END OF AJAX
    }); //END OF COMMENT CLICK LIKE FUNCTION
}); //End of For Loop
} end of funcrion
```

Code for generating button

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="InteractButt" data-likes=“'+res[index].post_id+'“
```

Buttons are generated dynamically where I put '// COMMENT HTML HERE'

Comment: Where is the Ajax button in your code, Please post html code here

Comment: Updated main question to add that in.

Comment: your quotes around `data-likes=“'+res[index].post_id+'“` look weird, is this just some copy-paste problem?

Comment: The problem is, that you are attaching the click event listener within the $.each function for all elements with [data-likes] attribute. So each time you iterate through your res array you attach another click listener. 

IMHO the easiest way to fix this, is to move the `}); //End of For Loop` before `$('[data-likes]').click(function() {`

Comment: cloned hit the nail on the head! Thank you. Can't believe I've lost so much time over a formatting issue... (I'm still a learning JQuery syntax...)